# Multiply values of two columns per row

Tags: python-3.x

I'd like to multiply the values of two columns per row...

from this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

Comment: Please share actual code/errors - not just some images.

Comment: Try do code it up and show your attempt. By the way what is the purpose of column `A`?

Comment: @BrunoVermeulen i am sorry, I am totaly new to this community as I am new to programming, I have absolutly no idea, how to do it.. need it for work (by the way, these tables are just schemes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can be easily done by numpy or pandas. Here is a sample solution-

```
import pandas as pd

column = ['A','B','C']
dataframe = pd.DataFrame({"A":['a','b','c'],"B":[1,2,3],"C":[2,2,2]})
dataframe['D'] = dataframe['B']*dataframe['C']

print(dataframe)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer using pandas is perfectly ok, but to learn Python it is perhaps better to start using the built-in functions first. Here is the answer using lists

```
my_list = []
my_list.append([1, 2])
my_list.append([2, 2])
my_list.append([3, 2])
print(my_list)

sum_list = []
for element in my_list:
    my_sum = element[0] + element[1]
    sum_list.append(element + [my_sum])

print(sum_list)
```

Result

```
[[1, 2], [2, 2], [3, 2]]
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 2, 4], [3, 2, 5]]
```

Your exercise to add the first column!